# .NET EntityFramework 6 relationship error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to create this relationship:
An invoice can have a collection of taxes, and an invoiceLine can also have a collection of taxes, and a tax can be related either to an invoice or to an invoiceLine. (but should be related to one of those)

I am getting this error:

```
Tax_invoice_line_Target_Tax_invoice_line_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.
```

the models:

model Invoice

```
public int id { get; set; }
//nav.props
public virtual ICollection<InvoiceLine> invoice_lines { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tax> taxes { get; set; }
```

model InvoiceLine

```
public int id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("invoice")]
public int id_invoice { get; set; }
//nav.props
public virtual Invoice invoice { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tax> taxes { get; set; }
```

model Tax

```
public int id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("invoice")]
public int? id_invoice { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("invoice_line")]
public int? id_invoice_line { get; set; }
//nav.props
public virtual Invoice invoice { get; set; }
public virtual InvoiceLine invoice_line { get; set; }
```

**UPDATE:**
ok, I made an error when writing the question... in InvoiceLine model, I was defining the Primary Key as composite, so the InvoiceLine model was in fact like this:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int id { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
[ForeignKey("invoice")]
public int id_invoice { get; set; }
//nav.props
public virtual Invoice invoice { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tax> taxes { get; set; }
```

After removing these two lines:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
```

it seems to be working (at least, I can create and apply migration without errors...).
But to be honest, I still dont get it...
so what if I would like to have the InvoiceLine PK as composite (including both id and the fk id_invoice)?
(note: I have never used composite keys before, so I am not sure if it would be a good idea in this case?)

Comment: What are the primary keys in these classes?

Comment: `InvoiceLine` should not have `taxes` since they can be indirectly referred by `invoiceLine.invoice.taxes`

Comment: @GertArnold the primary keys are "id" in all the models

Comment: @LeiYang: each invoiceLine can have n Taxes, but there can be also other (different) taxes applied to the invoice as a whole. It would be the same case if instead of Tax you think about Discount: every invoiceLine can have its own disccount (for example invoiceLine1 may have a 20% discount), and then another disccount applied globally to the invoice (for example another 5% applied globally to the invoice total)